# jQuery appendTo() not firing in IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, document-ready, appendto

I'm moving some stuff around on document ready. Think of it like a fancy tab navigation, where I have some dynamic content in a list navigation, that toggles between the different panels.

I do have control over the markup, but the ul is in a different template in the CMS from the one used to insert dynamic content, so I'm basically moving stuff around on document ready to get it where I want. It works great, except in IE7, where the move never occurs.

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="pnlHandler"></ul>

<div id="Panels">
   <li>Here goes the content that I want to move</li>
   <div class="pnlFront">
      This has more content, but it's already where I want it
   </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#Panels").children("li").appendTo(".pnlHandler");
});
```

Comment: You may have to remove them from the DOM first, then append them back to the `.pnlHandler`? I haven't tested this though...

Comment: IE doesn't like having `<li>`'s outside of `<ul>`'s.  So, my guess is that the `<li>` is never put into the DOM to start with, try to put it in a `<ul>` inside `#panels`.  Also, your selector should be `$("#panels")` (lower case 'p').

Comment: @Rocket: The li does render, but it does seem to be behaving strangely. If I inspect it, it thinks the next div is a child element (as if the li was never closed), even though the HTML is valid. Also, the ID for #Panel is correct in my version, I just typed it in incorrectly here. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE hates having `<li>`'s outside of a `<ul>`.  You need to have it inside a `<ul>` for it to work in IE.

```
<ul class="pnlHandler"></ul>

<div id="panels">
   <ul class="dummy">
     <li>Here goes the content that I want to move</li>
   </ul>
   <div class="pnlFront">
      This has more content, but it's already where I want it
   </div>
</div>
```

And then in your JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("ul.dummy", "#panels").children("li").appendTo(".pnlHandler");
   $("ul.dummy", "#panels").remove();
});
```

Comment: You are correct. Wrapping the li in a temporary ul did the trick. Makes sort of sense, when you think about it. Cheers.